# Vaadin Flow Redirect to Specific Route on Page Reload

Tags: routes, vaadin, reload, vaadin-flow

I am using Vaadin Flow. I am facing a problem that after I have navigated to a route and if I reload the page, i still land on the same page(Which is the way it should work I suppose). I wish to redirect to a specific route on reload. Something like capturing the reload event and redirecting to a specific route.

For Eg.

http://localhost:9090/user - The present route which I am presently at.

http://localhost:9090/ - The route to which I need to navigate on Reload of Page.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear whether you just want

a) alias or

b) to create a view that is shown only once and after that redirects the user else where.

For alias there is a very simple solution of using `@RouteAlias` annotation. This makes possible to add multiple routes to the view.

```
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
@RouteAlias(value = "main", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    ...
}
```

For the second case I would look into `BeforeEnterEvent`, which is fired during navigation and facilitates redirection (see: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle). You will need also `@PreserveOnRefresh`, since otherwise new instance of view will be created and count will be always zero.

```
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        if (count > 0) {
            event.forwardTo(OtherView.class);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

If you would rather restricts navigation to that view, so that it can only happen through your application and not by direct link (or refresh), then you can accomplish that with a `BeforeEnterObserver` and checking the `NavigationTrigger`.

It will be `PAGE_LOAD` when navigating directly by URL or when refreshing the browser tab, `ROUTER_LINK` when using a `RouterLink` and `UI_NAVIGATE` when using `UI#navigate`.

Note that a user can create a router link in the browser even if you haven't created one, so you shouldn't rely on that for security.

```
@Route
public class ExampleView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    public ExampleView() {
        add("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        if (beforeEnterEvent.getTrigger() == NavigationTrigger.PAGE_LOAD) {
            beforeEnterEvent.rerouteTo(MainView.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the @PreserveOnRefresh solved my issue.